# CSV: How to find next greater value in a list (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I have a code that reads a column in a CSV file and finds the best match for each element in a column from a given list. There are 3 columns: ZONE, Numbers, and ARPU. We are working with ARPU right now. The list is called (common_list), you will see it in a code

```
tp_usp15 = 1500
tp_usp23 = 2300
tp_usp27 = 2700
list_usp = [tp_usp15,tp_usp23, tp_usp27]

tp_bsnspls_s = 600
tp_bsnspls_steel = 1300
tp_bsnspls_chrome = 1800
list_bsnspls = [tp_bsnspls_s,tp_bsnspls_steel,tp_bsnspls_chrome

tp_bsnsrshn10 = 1000
tp_bsnsrshn15 = 1500
tp_bsnsrshn20 = 2000
list_bsnsrshn = [tp_bsnsrshn10,tp_bsnsrshn15,tp_bsnsrshn20]

common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('root of file.csv')

def get_plan(arpu):
    return min(common_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(arpu)))

df["Suggested plan"] = df["ARPU"].apply(get_plan)
df.to_csv('updated.csv')
```

It creates the 4th column called "Suggested PLan" and according to the code it finds BEST MATCHES from a common_list. But I need a code that will create another (5th column) that will have NEXT GREATER value from the list. For example, if the best match (4th column) is 600 and the next greater value in the list is 650, I want the code to find 650 and add it to the column. And same for every element in the column.
Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: This is confusing, please [edit] the question to give an example of `common_list`, it is not in the code (we could then run the script). Secondly, your code is creating `Suggested plan` not `BEST MATCHES`

Comment: @MartinEvans updated the question. common_list is a basic list of numbers [1000, 1500, 2000, and so on].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your `get_plan()` function to return the results for all columns at the same time.

Once you have determined the best result, the next highest is the next in `common_list`. [`bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) can be used to give you the index of the tuple in the list.

If already at the top of the list you can either return the highest again or `None` to indicate no higher value. Likewise for the lowest value, it is the next lower in `common_list` or if the lowest return it or possibly `None` (as required):

```
import pandas as pd
from bisect import bisect_left

def get_plans(p):
    best = min(common_list, key=lambda x : abs(x[0] - p['ARPU']))
    best_index = bisect_left(common_list, best)        # get location of best in common_list
    
    if best_index < len(common_list) - 1:
        next_greater = common_list[best_index + 1]
    else:
        next_greater = best                     # already highest

    if best_index > 0:
        next_lower = common_list[best_index - 1]
    else:
        next_lower = best                       # already lowest

    return [*best, *next_greater, *next_lower]


common_list = sorted([
    (1500, "usp15"),
    (2300, "usp23"),
    (2700, "usp27"),
    
    (600,  "bsnspls_s"),
    (1300, "bsnspls_steel"),
    (1800, "bsnspls_chrome"),

    (1000, "bsnsrshn10"),
    (1500, "bsnsrshn15"),
    (2000, "bsnsrshn20"),
])

fields = ['Suggest plan', 'Name 1', 'Next greater', 'Name 2', 'Next lower', 'Name 3']

df = pd.read_csv('root of file.csv')
df[fields] = df.apply(get_plans, axis=1, result_type="expand")
df.to_csv('updated.csv')
```

This would give:

```
   ZONE  Numbers  ARPU  Suggest plan         Name 1  Next greater      Name 2  Next lower          Name 3
0     0        5   600           600      bsnspls_s          1000  bsnsrshn10         600       bsnspls_s
1     1       10   300           600      bsnspls_s          1000  bsnsrshn10         600       bsnspls_s
2     2       20   400           600      bsnspls_s          1000  bsnsrshn10         600       bsnspls_s
3     2       30  1300          1300  bsnspls_steel          1500  bsnsrshn15        1000      bsnsrshn10
4     3       20  1400          1300  bsnspls_steel          1500  bsnsrshn15        1000      bsnsrshn10
5     3       20  1450          1500     bsnsrshn15          1500       usp15        1300   bsnspls_steel
6     3       20  1500          1500     bsnsrshn15          1500       usp15        1300   bsnspls_steel
7     4       20  2000          2000     bsnsrshn20          2300       usp23        1800  bsnspls_chrome
8     5       20     0           600      bsnspls_s          1000  bsnsrshn10         600       bsnspls_s
```

Comment: this example does a new sort for every call, that seems not very optimal

Comment: Is there any way to create new column that will now shower the result which is next lower (almost the same thing but this time lower value and not greater)?

Comment: Works perfectly! You have got the idea correctly and thanks million times for that. Can I ask: I have updated the code and actually, each value from the common_list has the name (check in the code). Is it possible that not only numeric value was recorded but also the corresponding name. For example: Suggested plan (numeric), Suggested plan (name), Next Greater (numeric), Next Greater (name), Next lower(numeric), Next lower (Name). Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: You would need to use text names (not variable names), also two have `1500` so `bsnsrsh15` would always take precedent

Comment: @MartinEvans so how can I realize it? I made close task to that where I also searched best match but by 2 variables and to get a name I used: best_match_overall = min(common_list, key=partial(distance_squared, list_client))
name_best_match_overall = [k for k,v in locals().items() if v == best_match_overall][0]. Any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: Using `locals()` is not advised as if ever another variable happens to have the same value, it would use that and give you incorrect results.

Comment: @MartinEvans and again! Work perfectly. Thanks million times. May you please have a look at this question (mine): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924521/csv-how-to-add-columns-to-list-and-find-best-match-closest-value-from-another                                                       It has the same task but this time search of BEST MATCH (as it here)  need to be done by 2 parameters (offnet calls and traffic), while here it was by ARPU. Thanks in advance!