# CSV: How to find name of the value from the list

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, match

I have a code that reads CSV file which has 3 columns: Zone, Number, and ARPU and I try to write a recommendation system that finds the best match for each value of ARPU from the list provided in the code (creates column "Suggested Plan"). Also, it finds the next greater value (creates column "Potential updated plan") and next lower value("Potential downgrade plan"):

```
tp_usp15 = 1500
tp_usp23 = 2300
tp_usp27 = 2700

list_usp = [tp_usp15,tp_usp23, tp_usp27]


tp_bsnspls_s = 600
tp_bsnspls_steel = 1300
tp_bsnspls_chrome = 1800


list_bsnspls = [tp_bsnspls_s,tp_bsnspls_steel,tp_bsnspls_chrome]

tp_bsnsrshn10 = 1000
tp_bsnsrshn15 = 1500
tp_bsnsrshn20 = 2000

list_bsnsrshn = [tp_bsnsrshn10,tp_bsnsrshn15,tp_bsnsrshn20]

#Common list#
common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn


import pandas as pd

def get_plans(p):
    best = min(common_list, key=lambda x : abs(x - p['ARPU']))
    best_index = common_list.index(best)        # get location of best in common_list
    
    if best_index < len(common_list) - 1:
        next_greater = common_list[best_index + 1]
    else:
        next_greater = best                     # already highest

    if best_index > 0:
        next_lower = common_list[best_index - 1]
    else:
        next_lower = best                       # already lowest

    return best, next_greater, next_lower

`common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn
common_list = sorted(common_list)   # ensure it is sorted
df = pd.read_csv('root/test.csv')
df[['Suggested plan', 'Potential updated plan', 'Potential downgraded plan']] = df.apply(get_plans, axis=1, result_type="expand")
df.to_csv('Recommendation System.csv') `
```

It creates 3 additional columns and does the corresponding task (best match or closes value, next greater value, and next smaller value).The code works perfectly but as you can see each numeric value has its name

***How to change the code to create additional columns with name next to new columns with numeric values?***

For example, right now code produces:
Zone, Number, ARPU, Suggested plan, Potential Updated Plan, and Potential downgrade plan

!BUT! I need to create:

Zone, Number, ARPU, Suggested plan (numeric), Suggested plan (name), Potential Updated Plan(numeric), Potential Updated Plan(name), Potential downgrade plan (numeric),Potential downgrade plan(name)

Where columns with (name) will show the corresponding name to the value used in (numeric) columns. Thanks in advance, guys!

Photo examples:
Here is the starting CSV file.
[image]

Then, after executing the code I have this:
[image]

And I want to create additional columns with corresponding names of valuables. Example columns in in yellow
[image]

Comment: Can you show your df to in your question? and then what's expected output?  Can't understand what's name that you are referring to

Comment: Please provide an [mre] (in this case the focus is: "minimal")

Comment: @Ank provided photo examples. Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas updated with some photos. Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: See also [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67905265/4985733) which includes names.

Comment: @MartinEvans please, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956916/csv-how-to-find-a-closest-match-closest-value-from-the-list-of-lists-list-that