# CSV: find best match/closest value by several parameters in 2 different CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a code that conducts a search of closest value between 2 CSV files. It reads a CSV file called "common_list" with some database which looks like this:

| common_name | common_Price | common_Offnet | common_Traffic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 1300 | 250 | 13000 |
| name2 | 1800 | 350 | 18000 |

The code puts these CSV rows into a list and then creates NumPy arrays.

```
common_list = pd.read_csv("common_list.csv")
common_list_offnet = common_list["common_Offnet"].to_list()
common_list_traffic = common_list["common_Traffic"].to_list()

array_offnet = np.array(common_list_offnet)
array_traffic = np.array(common_list_traffic)
array = np.column_stack((array_offnet,array_traffic))
```

We use this CSV file as a database for available cell phone plans (name of the plan, price, offnet calls, and internet traffic).

Then, the code reads another CSV file called "By_ARPU" with 100k+ rows with users and how they use their cell phone plans (how much money they spend (the price of plan), how much offnet calls, and traffic). The headers of this CSV file look like this:

| User ID | ARPU_AVERAGE | Offnet Calls | Traffic (MB) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

where ARPU_AVERAGE corresponds to the amount of money users spend (the price they pay). The code finds the closest value between the CSV files by 2 parameters:  **Offnet calls** and **Traffic (MB)**.

```
csv_data = pd.read_csv("By_ARPU.csv")

data = csv_data[['Offnet Calls', 'Traffic (MB)']]
data = data.to_numpy()

sol = []
for target in data:
    
    dist = np.sqrt((np.square(array[:,np.newaxis]-target).sum(axis=2))
    idx =  np.argmin(dist)
    sol.append(idx)

csv_data["Suggested Plan [SP]"] = common_list['common_name'][sol].values
csv_data["SP: Offnet Minutes"] = common_list['common_Offnet'][sol].values
csv_data["SP: Traffic"] = common_list['common_Traffic'][sol].values

csv_data.to_csv ('4.7 final.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

It finds closest value from the database and shows the name and corresponding offnet calls, traffic. For example, if in the file "By_ARPU" the values for Offnet calls and Traffic (MB) were 250 and 13000 respectively, it will show the name of closest value from "common_list" which is name1.

I wanted to create additional code for the same search but **with 3 parameters**. You can see that first database "common_list" has 3 parameters: **common_Price**, **common_Offnet** and **common_Offnet**. In the previous code, we found the closest value by 2 values.

Corresponding to each other columns in different CSV files were: "common_Offnet" from common_list - "Offnet calls" from By_ARPU **AND** "common_Traffic" from common_list - "Traffic (MB)" from By_ARPU.

And I want:

Find closest value by 3 parameters: Price, Offnet Calls and Traffic. The column which corresponds to the price in "By_ARPU" file is called "AVERAGE_APRU".

Please, help to modify the code to find closest value by making search by those 3 paramters instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
>>> plans
  common_name  common_Price  common_Offnet  common_Traffic
0       plan1          1300            250           13000
1       plan2          1800            350           18000

>>> df
  User ID  ARPU_AVERAGE  Offnet Calls  Traffic (MB)
0   Louis          1300           250         13000  # plan1 for sure (check 1)
1    Paul          1800           350         18000  # plan2, same values (check 2)
2    Alex          1500           260         14000  # plan1, probably
```

Create your matching function:

```
def rmse(user, plans):
    u = user[['ARPU_AVERAGE', 'Offnet Calls', 'Traffic (MB)']].values.astype(float)
    p =  plans[['common_Price', 'common_Offnet', 'common_Traffic']].values
    plan = np.sqrt(np.square(np.subtract(p, u)).mean(axis=1)).argmin()
    return plans.iloc[plan]['common_name']


df['Best Plan'] = df.apply(rmse, axis="columns", plans=plans)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  User ID  ARPU_AVERAGE  Offnet Calls  Traffic (MB) Best Plan
0   Louis          1300           250         13000     name1
1    Paul          1800           350         18000     name2
2    Alex          1500           260         14000     name1
```

**Edit**: Full code with you variable names:

```
common_list = pd.read_csv("common_list.csv")
csv_data = pd.read_csv("By_ARPU.csv")

find_the_best_plan = lambda target: np.sqrt(np.square(np.subtract(array, target)).mean(axis=1)).argmin()

array = common_list[['common_Price', 'common_Offnet', 'common_Traffic']].values
data = csv_data[['ARPU_AVERAGE', 'Offnet Calls', 'Traffic (MB)']].values

sol = np.apply_along_axis(find_the_best_plan, 1, data)

csv_data["Suggested Plan [SP]"] = common_list['common_name'].iloc[sol].values
csv_data["SP: Offnet Minutes"] = common_list['common_Offnet'].iloc[sol].values
csv_data["SP: Traffic"] = common_list['common_Traffic'].iloc[sol].values
```

Comment: Hi! It shows: rmse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'plans'. Am I doing some previous code wrong? May you please show how it could will look like in the full code

Comment: Check input data:  my `plans` is your `common_list` dataframe and my `df` is your `csv_data` dataframe.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I updated this moment, but still getting different errors. If it is not hard can you please update it with the same names as mine? sorry for that

Comment: @ThomasCuisance. I updated my code with your variable names. This is the full code.

Comment: Look it works fine and works the same concept as mine but it takes 5-10 minutes to execute while my previous code was executed in 30-40 seconds. Can the speed be improved? and what are reasons for taking so long?

Comment: @ThomasCuisance, I updated my answer. I think this should be faster than the previous one.

Comment: @ThomasCuisance, up?