# CSV: how to create a list from rows and find closest value of the list from the list containing lists?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a code that reads a column in a CSV file with 3 columns: Zone, Offnet calls, and Traffic.

If you need to copy/paste data. here are the first 10 rows from each column.

Offnet calls: 0, 421, 667, 12146, 7163, 5211, 1374, 3702, 1129, 2679, 4279

Traffic: 0, 30167, 23172, 215033,126514, 130045, 75357, 257846, 77677, 79331
[image]

I need "Offnet Calls" and "Traffic" to create a list. For example, row 3 will be [421, 30167] and make a search of best match/closest value from the list which contains lists of same parameters.
It will more clear by seeing the code:

```
tp_usp15 = [10, 200]
tp_usp23 = [15, 250]
tp_usp27 = [20, 300]
list_usp = [tp_usp15,tp_usp23, tp_usp27]

tp_bsnspls_s = [1,30]
tp_bsnspls_steel = [13,250]
tp_bsnspls_chrome = [18,350]
list_bsnspls = [tp_bsnspls_s,tp_bsnspls_steel,tp_bsnspls_chrome]

tp_bsnsrshn10 = [10,200]
tp_bsnsrshn15 = [15,300]
tp_bsnsrshn20 = [20,400]
list_bsnsrshn = [tp_bsnsrshn10,tp_bsnsrshn15,tp_bsnsrshn20]

common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn
```

For example, from this list provided in the code, the closest value/best match for row 3 = [421, 30167] is [20, 400] = tp_bsnsrshn20. And I need a code that will make the same operation for all the values in the CSV file. The closest value/best match needs to be recorded to the next column (a new column called "Best match" should be created right next to the "traffic" column). I have a code that works for inputs. 2 user inputs create a list and the search is done from the list of lists.

```
client_traffic = int(input("Enter the expected monthly traffic: "))
client_offnet = int(input("Enter monthly offnet calls: "))
list_client = [client_payment, client_offnet]

from functools import partial
def distance_squared(x, y):
    return (x[0] - y[0])**2 + (x[1] - y[1])**2
best_match_overall = min(common_list, key=partial(distance_squared, list_client))
name_best_match_overall = [k for k,v in locals().items() if v == best_match_overall][0]
```

How to apply this code to work for the whole CSV file. By the way, it gives also the name of value. I guess it should not be hard for advanced users to create some loop that will work by the same concept that I have provided in the last code but for the whole file.

Comment: To double-check, you are trying to read a CSV file that contains two columns and you trying to find the right closest value pairs to each row in the CVS file to given values, correct?

Comment: @Mazen correct! Any code ideas, pls?

Comment: I will work on it right now.

Answer (score 3):

## Update 2.0

You will need to store the data into a file like this (common_list):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# create data
common_list = {
    "common_name": ["tp_usp15","tp_usp23","tp_usp27","tp_bsnspls_s","tp_bsnspls_steel","tp_bsnspls_chrome","tp_bsnsrshn10","tp_bsnsrshn15","tp_bsnsrshn20"],
    "common_Offnet": [10,15,20,1,13,18,10,15,20],
    "common_Traffic": [200,250, 300,30,250,350,200,300,400]
}
common_list = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(common_list)
common_list.to_csv ('common_list.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Then to do what you want is by running the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

common_list = pd.read_csv("common_list.csv")
common_list_offnet = common_list["common_Offnet"].to_list()
common_list_traffic = common_list["common_Traffic"].to_list()

# convert csv_data to numpy array
array_offnet = np.array(common_list_offnet)
array_traffic = np.array(common_list_traffic)
array = np.column_stack((array_offnet,array_traffic))

# reading data
csv_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
#data = csv_data.drop(['Zone'], axis=1)
data = csv_data[['Offnet', 'Traffic']]
# convert csv_data to numpy array
data = data.to_numpy()

# get the closest points
sol = []
for target in data:
    # compute distance
    dist = np.sqrt((np.square(array[:,np.newaxis]-target).sum(axis=2)))
    # get the index of the lowest value
    idx =  np.argmin(dist)
    sol.append(idx)
# print answers
csv_data["best_name"] = common_list['common_name'][sol].values
csv_data["best_Offnet"] = common_list['common_Offnet'][sol].values
csv_data["best_Traffic"] = common_list['common_Traffic'][sol].values
csv_data.to_csv ('updated.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

For the easiness of handling later in your process, I have set the two values for the best solution into two different columns so you won't need to spend time pre-process the data, which is an annoying process.

## Updated answer

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

...
common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn

# convert csv_data to numpy array
array = np.array(common_list)

# reading data
csv_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
data = csv_data.drop(['Zone'], axis=1)
# convert csv_data to numpy array
data = data.to_numpy()

# get the closest points
sol = []
for target in data:
    # compute distance
    dist = np.sqrt((np.square(array[:,np.newaxis]-target).sum(axis=2)))
    # get the index of the lowest value
    idx =  np.argmin(dist)
    sol.append(idx)
# print answers
print(array[sol])
csv_data["index"] = sol
csv_data["values"] = array[sol].tolist()
csv_data.to_csv ('updated.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

## Old answer

Here is an example (with dummy data) to test the code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# reading data
csv_data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

# convert csv_data to numpy array
array = csv_data.to_numpy()

# ask for target data
client_traffic = int(input("Enter the expected monthly traffic: "))
client_offnet = int(input("Enter monthly offnet calls: "))
example = [client_offnet, client_traffic]


answers = []
# convert example to numpy array
target = np.array(example)
# gets the index of the closest value
best_match_overall =  np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(array - target,keepdims=True))
answers.append(best_match_overall)
```

Comment: But "Offnet calls" and "Traffic" is not limited by those 10 values. There are 2 whole columns as on screenshot

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code snippet needed to have what you want.

Comment: There is no input. Value for offnet calls and traffic is taken from columns of CSV file

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to find the closest by comparing the input and the csv data? You have answered to my question before with `correct`, which that what I have done.

Comment: Look, We have 2 needed columns: Offnet calls and Traffic. I have created a comparison list INSIDE THE CODE. Check the first code which creates a list called common_list. I need that for every row in the CSV code will find the best match/closest value from the common_list. Please check what is common_list in the first part of the code that I have provided

Comment: Check what this code does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900445/csv-how-to-find-next-greater-value-in-a-list-python/67905265#67905265        I need the same concept and result but THIS TIME, search should be done by 2 variables (Offnet calls, Traffic) and in the example I sent you, the search is done by 1 variable - ARPU

Comment: Does it work for you? I have got: dist = np.sqrt((np.square(array[:,np.newaxis]-target).sum(axis=2)))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (32,1,2) (3,)

Comment: Could you share your data in csv? I have tested it and it works.

Comment: please, find it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13LZQzJHeibTWmxx3i4yyXKCc4HBOvXFe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the code, so basically, the issue was you have an additional column called "Zone" that should be removed when processing the data.

Comment: I see it is printing some shorten version of results, is it possible to record the results in the new column inside the CSV? (for example called "Best match") (as in example, I sent previously)

Comment: Do you want a new column to store the index of the best answer or contain the values themsevles?

Comment: Could it be both? 2 new columns: one with values and one with index

Comment: Added export option.

Comment: yeah, regarding the values that is everything I wanted. We got a different understanding of index, is it possible that despite numeric index (which is printing by your code right now), we will have the name of the corresponding value. For example, tp_usp15 = [10, 200] and in the "index" column it will write "tp_usp15"?

Comment: The name of the variable? I don't think this is possible the way that you have done it but I have an idea. I will try it.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Working hella good, brotha. One last question: if there will be some other columns (for example it could be excel/csv with a lot of not related columns) - should I just add this columns to the "drop" line?

Comment: Yup! I can update the code to make it more robust to any number of columns, so rather than drop X, Y, etc., select what I want.

Comment: Updated my solution.